# What is this port on my Samsung phone?

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-s-4-mini

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini, what's this in the screenshot below:

[image: Marked in red]

Comment: Have you looked into the manual that came with your phone..? or [Online Manual](http://support.bell.ca/_web/Guides/User-Guides/Mobile/Samsung/Samsung-EN/Samsung-Galaxy-S4-mini-user-guide.pdf)?

Comment: @Lucky I can't find anything in the guide.

Comment: Isn't that an antenna of some kind? I believe there are two other antenna's up top, WiFi, GSM and I think the bottom one is Bluetooth.

Comment: @Tom if it's a GSM antenna can someone confirm that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saw the whole back of the Samsung S4 mini and I believe that is the only one there on the back.

It's definitely the GSM antenna.

The hole there is on purpose. This way the phone gets a better reception.
Sometimes, a void sticker gets put on there.

Check this video to hear about this port (on the S4):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9pDB1kGmLY

More questions answered about these kind of ports:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2342889
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1625663